# What are good ways of simulating transactions in mainnet?

Tags: tezos-client, api

Is it possible to dry-run transactions before signing and broadcasting them, and if so, what are some good options?
I'm pretty language agnostic.

E.g. if I'm interacting with a DEX, I'd like to see how my token balances would change before actually sending the transaction.

I was hoping to find something like this in the `tezos-node` RPC API, but no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tezos-client transfer` command takes the `--dry-run` flag that will simulate a transaction instead of injecting it. It will show you any updates of storage and balances that would've been performed if the transaction is successful and immediately applied on node's blockchain state.

If you want to do this programmatically using the node's RPC API, you can pass the `-l` flag to `tezos-client` to see the RPC calls used for this.